# Word request for "one's inablity to understand his/her duty/obligation"

Tags: single-word-requests

A word for a situation when you are completely confused/unable to understand your duty/obligation.

T̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶i̶d̶i̶o̶m̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶e̶x̶t̶:̶

> Damned if I do, damned if I don't"

T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶d̶i̶o̶m̶ ̶p̶e̶r̶f̶e̶c̶t̶l̶y̶ ̶f̶i̶t̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶i̶t̶u̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ but is there also any dictionary word for this situation?

Words like **befuddle/bewilder** have meaning related to "unable to think clearly", but I am not quite sure whether they also relate to:"one's inability to understand his/her duty/obligation".

Is there is any better word for this situation. Please suggest.

---

Edit:

I didn't understand the meaning of idiom, so I have strikethrough it. Plesae disregard it.

Comment: That idiom doesn't mean you don't understand your obligations, it means that it is impossible for you to fulfil them. A catch-22.

Comment: @curiousdannii it clearly indicates that I didn't understand the idiom too.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you're *unable* to understand something, then it is beyond your intellectual capacity, so words or phrases like '(too) dumb', '(too) stupid' or 'it's beyond me' would work. However, a sense of duty or (social or moral) obligation has intellectual, emotional and instinctive components to it. The inability to connect these to a given situation would imply autism, emotional stupidity or immaturity. Are you sure you mean 'unable to ...'?

Comment: I think he/she might mean that your duty is unclear to you, rather than that you're unable to understand it.

Comment: This situation is related to a mentally sound person, who is unable to understand his duties out of some confusion.He is unable to decide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**torn**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tear#tear) might work

> (be torn) Be in a state of uncertainty between two conflicting options or parties:
>
> *When his best friend gets involved in a street clash, Ricky is torn between past loyalties and his desire to start a new life with his girlfriend.*

---

Also try **[conflicted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conflict?q=conflicted#conflict__12)**

> (as adjective conflicted) Having or showing confused and mutually inconsistent feelings:
>
> *he remains a little conflicted about Marlene*

[Oxford]

Answer (score 0):

Being unable to perform his or her duties would make a person **incompetent** .

> [incompetent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incompetent) (adj.) - Not having or showing the necessary skills to do something successfully; not qualified to act in a particular capacity